# How to save many files with specific ids where ids are in int8 format using psycopg2?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to get data from a table "entries" in a database where i already have a dataframe of specific instances (log_id) in attribute "file_id". The problem is that I cant ask for int8 in iteration mode for example the code below doesn't work how to save each file in the iteration.

```
log_id ={DataFrame:(4,1)}

for item in log_id[0]:
    extract = ' SELECT * From "entries" WHERE "Entries"."file_id" 
    = ??;'
    b=cur.execute(extract, [item])
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('log'+item+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    b.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: The placeholder for psycopg2 is usually `%s`, not `??`.  The variable `b` will have the value `None`, it does not have a `to_excel` method.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I used ?? as I didn't know what to use however %s work s for strings not for int8 type, Can you give me an idea how to fix the code?

Comment: `%s` is used for all placeholders - see [the docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Parameter substitution and string formatting are not the same (although unfortunately they _look_ the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine!

```
for item in logid_r[0]:

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."file_id" = %(int)s;',  {'int': item} )

    datapoints = cur.fetchall()
    cols = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    datalog = pd.DataFrame(datapoints, columns=cols) 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('log' + str(item) + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    datalog.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    writer.save()
```